# Order of column names with keys() in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Can I rely on keys() to always return column names in the same order as the query results when selecting *all columns*?  Based on my output it appears to be  true, but I can't find any documentation that guarantees it.  I'm inclined to think it is true because while dictionaries may be unordered, they should be consistent.

```
    # Loop through each table in the database where all tables 
    # are being reflected at once.
    for table in Base.metadata.tables.values():

        # Select all columns
        rows = Session.query(table).all()

        # Prepend a header row
        rows.insert(0, rows[0].keys())

        # Output to file
        fh = open(filename, 'wb')
        outcsv = unicodecsv.writer(fh)
        outcsv.writerows(rows)
        fh.close
```

Similarly, column_descriptions also appears to return names in the same order as the values, but again I am not certain if it will always be true.

```
    # Prepend list of column names as the first row
    rows.insert(0, [col['name'] for col in Session.query(table).column_descriptions])
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Antti. Since I didn't explicitly define any mapper classes (i.e., I'm reflecting all tables at once).  I wasn't sure if I was in ORM land or not, and therefore wasn't sure if that bit of documentation applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows returned are [KeyedTuple](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple)s; the ordering of them in 1 query is dictated by the order of the columns in the original select, which will absolutely guarantee that the order is the same as returned by `.keys()`, and the same for each item of in the same query results.